# Please correct my use of the Maybe Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm implementing a little program that does exponentiation ciphers. Some of the computations might fail, for instance, computing a modular inverse. I've used Maybe to deal with these sorts of failures. But now I'm stuck, as I need to "inject" the value inside of a maybe into another partially applied function. I know that if I had a function that took one argument, I'd use bind to do this.

```
import Data.Char
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

extendedGcd::Integer->Integer->(Integer, Integer)
extendedGcd a b | r == 0 = (0, 1)
                | otherwise = (y, x - (y * d))
                where
                    (d, r) = a `divMod` b
                    (x, y) = extendedGcd b r

modularInverse::Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
modularInverse n b | relativelyPrime n b = Just . fst $ extGcd n b
                   | otherwise = Nothing
                   where
                        extGcd = extendedGcd

relativelyPrime::Integer->Integer->Bool
relativelyPrime m n | gcd m n == 1 = True
                    | otherwise = False

textToDigits::String->[Integer]
textToDigits p = map (\x->toInteger (ord x - 97)) p

digitsToText::[Integer]->String
digitsToText d = map (\x->chr ((fromIntegral x) + 97)) d

exptEncipher::Integer->Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
exptEncipher m k p | relativelyPrime k (p - 1) = Just $ powerMod p k m 
                   | otherwise = Nothing

exptDecipher::Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer
exptDecipher m q c = powerMod c q m

exptEncipherString::Integer->Integer->String->[Maybe Integer]
exptEncipherString m k p = map (exptEncipher m k) plaintext
    where
        plaintext = textToDigits p

exptDecipherString::Integer->Integer->[Maybe Integer]->Maybe String
exptDecipherString m k c = (fmap digitsToText) plaintext
    where
        q = modularInverse k (m - 1)
        plaintext = map (fmap $ exptDecipher m q) c
```

Specifically, my problem is in the function exptDecipherString, where I needed to inject the value encapsulated by the monad in q into the function exptDecipher, which I will then lift to work on c. What's the right way to do this? Also, I'm worried that I'll end up with a list of [Maybe Char] instead of the Maybe String that I want. I'm having problems reasoning through all of this. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Have a look at the do-notation section here, it is helpful for maybe also: http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#do-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sequence`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3asequence) and [`ap`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3aap) to get the types to work out. First for their signatures:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

Notice that `sequence` directly addresses your worry about having a `[Maybe Char]` instead of a `Maybe String`. Both are in `Control.Monad` (note that you'll have to import `ap`). We can use them as follows:

```
exptDecipherString :: Integer -> Integer -> [Maybe Integer] -> Maybe String
exptDecipherString m k c = fmap digitsToText plaintext
  where
    q = modularInverse k (m - 1)
    plaintext = sequence $ map (ap $ fmap (exptDecipher m) q) c
```

We can get to this point by working through the types. First we appy `exptDecipher` to `m`, which gives us a function of type `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. We want to apply this to `q`, but it's a `Maybe Integer`, so we have to use `fmap (exptDecipher m) q`, which then has type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)`. We can then pop `ap` on the front and get something of type `Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer`. We then map this over `c`, which gives us a `[Maybe Integer]`, which we can turn inside out using `sequence`.

This might not work—if there are bugs in the logic, etc.—but at least it compiles.

A couple of side notes: you can use the infix operators `<$>` and `<*>` from `Control.Applicative` in place of `fmap` and `ap`, respectively, for slightly nicer syntax, and your `relativelyPrime` can be written much more simply as `relativelyPrime m n = gcd m n == 1`.

Comment: Okay, I'm mostly getting this, but I'm confused about the type of fmap (exptDecipher m) q. Why is it what you say it is? I'm looking at the type fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b and I can't see why that would be what you say it is. I'm feeding it a function from Integer->Integer and then a value Just Integer. At this point, haven't we fed it too many values?

Comment: fmap that is. Sorry this is such a weird question. I was looking at applicative functor myself, but I'm afraid I don't completely get it. Before you answered, I had changed my code to (exptDecipher <$> (pure m) <*> q) and it still wasn't compiling.

Comment: Whoops. I get it. It's been a long day. I misread the type signature of my own function. Doh!

Comment: As a quick followup, I ran hlint on this, and found that mapM is equivalent to sequence . map

Comment: Yes—there are a number of things you could do to make the code a little tighter. I was using `sequence` since it exactly matched up with your question about `[Maybe Char]`.

Comment: Yeah, it also suggested "eta reduce" whatever that means, by removing arguments to a few functions. I'm still a bit of a Haskell noob. Thanks so much for your help though.